# I am not able to make Google Pie chart to work inside Polymer 1.0 custom element

Tags: google-visualization, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement a Google Pie Chart object in my Polymer 1.0 application. This is how my custom element looks:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<dom-module id="points-from-customer">
  <template>
    <style>
        :host
        {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
      (function () {
          'use strict';

          Polymer({
              is: 'points-from-customer',

              properties: {
                  foo: {
                      type: String,
                      value: 'points-from-customer',
                      notify: true
                  }
              },

              ready: function () {
                  //Reference URL: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

                  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
                  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                  function drawChart() {
                      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                                      ['Work', 11],
                                      ['Eat', 2],
                                      ['Commute', 2],
                                      ['Watch TV', 2],
                                      ['Sleep', 7]
                                ]);

                      var options = {
                          title: 'My Daily Activities'
                      };

                      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                      chart.draw(data, options);
                  }
              }
          });
      })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When I am consuming the element in my custom element the application browser status bar saying "Read google.com..." and nothing happens.
As an alternative I removed the reference

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

from my custom element and put it to index.html. But I still see the same.

**Questions are:**

1. What wrong I am doing and where?
2. Is this at all compatible with Polymer framework? Can this be used as a web-component. If yes, please let me know the installation method/syntax using bower.
3. The data passed into drawChart function does not look like a real JSON object / string. Can I pass a proper JSON format here. If not, can I just generate the string the way it shows and pass it directly to arrayToDatatable method using a variable?

When I am running the application `console` shows me this big error:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data1449040231565' of null
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
getData @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:127
addEvent @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:127
n.init @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:127
n.init @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:127
n.init @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:127
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Socket.onevent @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Socket.onpacket @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Manager.ondecoded @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Decoder.add @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:3
Manager.ondata @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Socket.onPacket @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Transport.onPacket @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
callback @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
exports.decodePayloadAsBinary @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
exports.decodePayload @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
Polling.onData @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
Emitter.emit @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:1
Request.onData @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
Request.onLoad @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
xhr.onreadystatechange @ browser-sync-client.2.7.6.js:2
```

I am not sure if this comes from `Google Chart`, but when I remove the code from my `custom element`, above list disappears and page loads fine. So I thought they could be related!

Thanks in advance